# Use Redis Cache in production environment

Tags: docker, redis, microservices

i have a microservice (webapi .NET) to deploy with Docker in K8S.
Internally, in docker compose file, i use a image of Redis as cache.
In development environment everything is ok, my question is: in production which is the best practice? use an image of Redis in the pod, or reference to an external Redis service (es. Azure, AWS, etc)?

THanks for any advice

Comment: Particularly for something you're using only as a cache, if persistence doesn't particularly matter, either approach is fine.  In general my experience has been that cloud-hosted data stores are easier to back up and otherwise maintain, but also somewhat more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitnami Helm Chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/redis/helm) to deploy Redis in your Kubernetes environment.

It uses non-root Redis container image and is highly configurable. You can find more information about deployment options and configuration at their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis/#installing-the-chart).